# Using "Excuse me, ..." for asking questions

Tags: conversation

It has happened to me a lot that I stop random people in the street for asking a question about direction. I said "Excuse me". In answer to my "excuse me" People usually say "Hey". I am wondering if I should say "Hello" in response to them or not. I don't actually know how to answer their "hey".

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You should probably ask this on [interpersonal.se] instead. This site is about English linguistics and the nuts and bolts of the English Language.

Comment: Nowadays, I'd just read "Hey[!]" as "Hi ...You seem like a nice guy ... How can I help?" It's short, punchy, and eliminates the saccharine nuances of "How may I be of service?" etc. But as you are aware, it's not always clear what the response of the addressee actually means. // 50 years ago in the UK, I'd have interpreted it rather as "What do you think you're doing, taking up my time!" (but it was thankfully quite a rare response then).

Comment: Likely it's not "Hey" but rather a garbled "Yeah".

Answer (score 1):

Your "*Excuse me?!*" is an apology for saying "*Excuse me*", for interrupting them and claiming their time.  (It's not "*Sorry*", because your interruption was deliberate and you would do it again under the same circumstances.)

The "*Hey!*" (or "*What?*", or "*Yes?*", or even "*Hello?*") response means "*Okay, you've got my attention, what do you want?*".

You are now already in conversation mode, so "*Hello!*" wouldn't be appropriate.
Just get on with it and ask your question.

(In geek-talk, it is the equivalent of [RTS/CTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11_RTS/CTS), request-to-send/clear-to-send.)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, "excuse me" is a way of saying "hello" if that's how you started the conversation. In response to the "hey", you could just ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase: **Excuse me**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65969?redirectedFrom=excuse%20me#eid4981030)

> used as a polite form in addressing a stranger, or in interrupting the
>   speech of another.

As in your question:

In answer to my "excuse me", People usually say "Hey". You can greet them if you like or simply proceed with you question.